# DB50QT-11 engine cuts out

Tags: clutch

purchased this DB50QT-11 as a none runner, fitted a new carb and it starts first time, but only when it's on the stand, if I stop the rear wheel from rotating it causes the engine to stop, I have a feeling it's the clutch, but just thought I'd ask advice first.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the transmission - and you don't say, there should be a neutral - so either the centrifugal clutch is stuck or broken or the plate clutch has stuck.

Whichever it is - the clutch needs investigating.

Comment: It's a rev and go 50cc, I assumed it would be the clutch, but just thought I'd check, this is my first experience with a Chinese bike, got it nice and cheap just to play around with, thank you for your reply